# Are there significant differences between EASA and FAA when teaching jet aircraft performance?

Tags: faa-regulations, regulations, easa-regulations, performance-calculation

Both regulatory bodies did a great effort in regulation harmonization, but I'm looking for any significant differences (if any) in how is taught the subject from the pilot point of view, i.e. differences in landing and takeoff performance terminology and data calculation.

Comment: Define “significant”.  I assume you use it to means differences where the outcome or decision made would be different.  Calculations go back to physics so there should be no difference in calculation results.

Comment: I suspect you’re going to find much greater variations between manufacturers than between regulators. US regulations don’t say much at all about performance (or how to teach it) other than that you must adhere to the limitations in the AFM/POH.

Comment: @Jim. Of course physics is the same. Significant in this context means any differences in climb gradient, factors, flap setting for takeoff or go around, takeoff or approach speed calculation, etc. Also distances and allowances for dry and wet runways (even definition of contaminated runways).

Comment: @StephenS. As an example, the calculation for unfactored landing distances are based on Regulation 135.385 (b) (FAA ) and CAT.POL.A.230 (EASA). Here are some differences in terms and definitions and also in how to calculate those factors in wet and dry runways.

Comment: Regulators aren’t the ones that determine flap settings, takeoff/approach speeds, or dry/wet runway performance.  That’s done by the aircraft manufacturer.